How to add filter on "Subject" for Gmail watch Push notification Api
I want to get only those emails which have a certain subject. For example subject_filter = 'Pokemon', then only emails with subject containing the word 'Pokemon' should be eligible for push notification.
I read the docs but could not find anything related to this in the docs.
